# I want to calculate this Integral to solve one important differential equation in general relativity

Tags: math

∫▒fdf/√(f(f^3 a+6bf+3c))
a, b, c are constant

Answer (score 2):

The program is:

```
 Integrate[x/Sqrt[x (x^3 a + 6 b x + 3 c )], x]
```

As per Mathematica output:

```
(2*(EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[(x*(-R[1] + R[3]))/((x - R[1])*R[3])]], 
                             ((R[1] - R[2])*R[3])/(R[2]*(R[1] - R[3]))] -       
    EllipticPi[R[3]/(-R[1] + R[3]), 
             ArcSin[Sqrt[(x*(-R[1] + R[3]))/((x - R[1])*R[3])]], 

                ((R[1] - R[2])*R[3])/(R[2]*(R[1] - R[3]))])*(x - R[1])^2*

                Sqrt[(R[1]*(x - R[2]))/((x - R[1])*R[2])]*R[3]*
                Sqrt[x*R[1]*(x - R[3])*(-R[1] + R[3]^2)])/
               (Sqrt[x*(3*c + 6*b*x + a*x^3)]* (R[1] - R[3]))
```

Where:

```
         Root[n]
```

Is the n root of the polynomial

```
         p[u]=3 c + 6 b u + a u^3
```

Additionally, you may try this in [Wolfram Alpha](http://tinyurl.com/2ae57kt) to get the indefinite integral, or definite ones. But I really think that if you are solving **one important differential equation in general relativity** and don't tried Mathematica and/or Wolfram Alpha, you may be a) Trolling or b) In great trouble